# Kubernetes error code 403: user anonymous cannot get path

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I been trying to install kubernetes for the first time, after the initial setup, I was finally able to execute the kube-up.bash script:

```
kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.bash
```

Everything goes well and I even see the list of cluster services installed:

[image: clusters installed]

Then the book I am checking says: 
"Go to: https//your_master_ip/ui/"

But when I try I can only see the following:

[image: Error code 403]

I assumed I did not performed a proper setup on during the auth process, so I did:

```
gcloud auth list
```

But my active account is there with my Google email, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am able to access the Google Cloud Platfrom and see the project I created for this, I can see the traffic also.

Also, the kubectl commands are not working on my system, it throws a bash error that It was not able to locate the order.

Can someone please assist me?

Regards

Comment: _Go to `master-ip/ui/`_ is horrifically outdated, and even references to the kubernetes dashboard should be taken with a grain of salt, since it's deprecated as well. The tl;dr is that there is no current graphical management toy in _pure_ kubernetes, although some of the other distributions (Canonical, OpenShift, Rancher, etc) may include one

Comment: _Also, the kubectl commands are not working on my system, it throws a bash error that It was not able to locate the order_ You'll have to include the actual error text before anyone can help you. But, if it is as simple as trying to run `kubectl` and receiving `command not found`, [that is easy to solve](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)

Comment: Hi @MatthewLDaniel thank you, actually the book never says that I should install kuvectl, I thought it was something that come with the kube-up script.

Actually I noticed some other missing stuff from the book, I am writing my own way to install it and dont die in the process.
The message reads:
'[smartinez@localhost .kube]$ kubectl cluster-info
bash: kubectl: no se encontró la orden...'

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I just installed the kubectl and it is working now. Thanks